# No se dispara el evento click luego de recargar el contenido mendiante una petición AJAX en Symfony2

Tags: jquery, ajax, eventos

Tengo el siguiente **controller** :

```php
public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        if (!$request->isXmlHttpRequest())
        {
            $this->denyAccessUnlessGranted('ROLE_ESP_NAC', null, 'Imposible acceder a este recurso !!');

            $repositoryRiesgos = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Riesgo');


            $listado = $repositoryRiesgos->findAll(); //findByPages($request->get('page', 1));
            return $this->render('AppBundle:CodifRiesgos:index.html.twig', array('riesgos' => $listado));
        } else
        {
            try
            {
                $this->denyAccessUnlessGranted('ROLE_ESP_NAC', null, 'Imposible acceder a este recurso !!');
            } catch (AccessDeniedException $denyExc)
            {
                return new Response($denyExc->getMessage(), 403);
            }

            $repositoryRiesgos = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Riesgo');
            $listado = $repositoryRiesgos->findAll();

            return $this->render('AppBundle:CodifRiesgos:tablaRiesgos.html.twig', array('riesgos' => $listado));
        }
    }
```

Incluso en el controller prácticamente repetí el código tanto para la petición vía AJAX como la normal.

Ahora bien la **plantilla `index.html.twig`** es la siguiente:

```
{% extends "::base.html.twig" %}

{% block title %} PAMI - Codificadores {% endblock %}

{% block principal %}    
    <br/>
    <div class="breadcrumb">        
        <a href="{{ path('app_homepage') }}">Inicio<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></a>&nbsp;
        Riesgos<a class="lnkRecargarRiesgos" href="{{ path('riesgos_listado') }}"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span></a>               
    </div>           

    <div id="tablaDatos">
        <table id="tablaRiesgos" class="table table-condensed table-hover table-responsive">
            <thead>
                {% if app.user and is_granted('ROLE_ESP_NAC') %}
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="5"><a id="lnkRegistrarRiesgo" href="{{ path('riesgos_registrar_nuevo') }}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Nuevo</a></th>
                    </tr>               
                {% endif %}
                <tr>
                    <th>Nombre</th>
                    <th>Descripci&oacute;n</th>
                    <th>Alto</th>
                    <th>Editar</th>
                    <th>Eliminar</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {% for riesgo in riesgos%}
                    <tr id="filaRiesgo_{{ riesgo.id }}">
                        <td>{{ riesgo.nombre }}</td>
                        <td>{{ riesgo.descripcion }}</td>
                        <td>
                            {% if riesgo.calificaComoAltoRiesgo %}
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-hand-up"></span>
                            {% endif %}
                        </td>
                        <td><a class="lnkEditarRiesgo" href="{{ path('riesgos_editar', {'id':riesgo.id}) }}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></a></td>
                        <td><a class="lnkEliminarRiesgo" href="{{ path('riesgos_eliminar', {'id':riesgo.id}) }}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a></td>
                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </tbody>            
        </table>   
    </div>

{% endblock %}

{% block javascripts %}
    {{ parent() }}
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){

            $('a.lnkRecargarRiesgos').on('click', function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var url = $(this).attr('href');
                    $.ajax({
                        'datatypes': 'html',
                        'type': 'GET',
                        'url': url,
                        beforeSend: function() {
                            $('#indicador').addClass('cargando-satisfactorio').fadeIn('fast');
                        }
                    }).done(function(data) {
                        $('#tablaDatos').html(data);
                    }).fail(function(jqXHR) {
                        $('#indicador').removeClass('cargando-satisfactorio').addClass('cargando-error').html(jqXHR.responseText);
                    }).always(function() {
                        $('#indicador').fadeOut('slow', function() {
                            $(this).removeClass('cargando-error').html("<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-time'></span> Cargando...");
                        });
                    });
                });           


                $('#tablaRiesgos tbody tr a.lnkEliminarRiesgo').on('click', function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var idRiesgo = $(this).attr('id');
                    var url=$(this).attr('href');
                    var trPadre=$(this).parents('tr');
                    $.ajax({
                        'datatypes': 'html',
                        'type': 'GET',
                        'url': url,
                        beforeSend: function() {
                            $('#indicador').addClass('cargando-satisfactorio').fadeIn('fast');
                        }
                    }).done(function(data) {
                        $(trPadre).remove();
                        $('#indicador').html(data);
                    }).fail(function(jqXHR) {
                        $('#indicador').removeClass('cargando-satisfactorio').addClass('cargando-error').html(jqXHR.responseText);
                    }).always(function() {
                        $('#indicador').fadeOut(4900, function() {
                            $(this).removeClass('cargando-error').html("<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-time'></span> Cargando...");
                        });
                    });
                });
        });
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

El problema es el siguiente:

1. Cuando la plantilla es cargada inicialmente, el evento `onclick` asociado al `a.lnkEliminarRiesgo` funciona correctamente.
2. Luego, al hacer click en el `a.lnkRecargarRiesgos`, recargo la misma información actualizada (mediante AJAX) en `div#tablaDatos`.
3. Pero ahora, como se volvió a generar el `a.lnkEliminarRiesgo`, **no se dispara el evento `.on('click',...` que había asociado originalmente**. En cambio, se sigue el enlace del `href` porque no se ejecutó `e.preventDefault()`.

Yo quiero que el evento on click siga funcionando igual que al inicio.

No sé si es que mi enfoque del trabajo con las plantillas en Symfony2 es incorrecto o me falta algo o no estoy enfocando bien el uso de las llamadas asíncronas, o la forma en que estoy incluyendo el JavaScript.

Comment: Hola @Francisco. Me tomé la libertad de editar tu pregunta con la intención de que quede más clara. Si hay algo con lo que no estés de acuerdo, no dudes en revertir el cambio, [edit] la pregunta nuevamente o comentarlo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A la hora de bindear las eventos, inicié el filtro en una etiqueta `div` con `id='vistas'`, que para esta aplicación en específico será en ese elemento donde se carguen todas las vistas de las llamadas AJAX, por tanto este no desaparecerá de la página. Y en el caso de la funcionalidad eliminar, siempre se realiza en una tabla con id='tablaDatos'
 `$('#vistas').find('#tablaDatos tbody tr a.lnkEliminarRegistro').on('click', function(e) { ... }`

De esta manera se mantendrá siempre el vínculo del evento `click` sobre las etiquetas `<a>` con clase, por ejemplo: `lnkEliminarRegistro`.

De esa manera me sirve la implementación para la funcionalidad eliminar de todas las tablas de las vistas cargadas dentro de `<div class='vistas'></div>`

Answer (score 1):

Te recomiendo enlazarlo de esta manera:

```
$(document).on("click",'a.lnkEliminarRiesgo', function (event, xhr, settings) {
//Contenido Script
});
```

En las respuestas anteriores el *bind* está hecho al `body`, si el `body` cambia puede romperse el *bind* o incluso generar algo conocido como "double firing"... por eso lo recomendado es hacer el enlace al documento. También se instancia a parte del evento, el callback `xhr` y `settings`, los cuales pueden ayudarte en el debug.

También tendrías que revisar si que la funcion si requiere de algún plugging siga esta tendencia o tendrás que recargar los plugging N cantidades de veces y hacer el unbind roto.

Comment: ¿Cómo es esta respuesta diferente a las dos que ya hay en la publicación? (y que parecen más detalladas y mejores porque describen por qué eso solucionaría el problema)

Comment: en las anteriores el bind esta hecho al body, si el body cambia puede romperse el bind o incluso generar algo conocido como "double firing"... por eso lo recomendado es hacer el enlace al documento, tambien se instancia a parte del evento, el callback xhr y Settings, el cual puede ayudarte en el debug.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644418/jquery-ajax-option-xhr

Comment: son iguales en el ámbito de que solucionan el mismo problema el detalle esta en aprovechar mejor la tecnología.

Comment: xhr (Function): Callback for creating the XMLHttpRequest object. Defaults to the ActiveXObject when available (IE), the XMLHttpRequest otherwise. Override to provide your own implementation for XMLHttpRequest or enhancements to the factory.It's not available in jQuery 1.2.6 and in any early version.

Comment: Todo esto debería ir en la respuesta directamente, y no en los comentarios :)

Comment: se supone que si esta usando jquery debe conocer los setting básicos que utiliza el llamado de funciones anónimas ...

Comment: ademas se los ejemplo lo que no entienda debería ser tema de investigación de parte del usuario. y si no sabe que tome un curso de jquery.

Comment: Me parece que le estás dando demasiado crédito a mucha gente que quizás no debería tenerlo. Conozco gente que usa jQuery y seguramente no sabe ni qué es una variable :P

Comment: bueno la idea es darles la respuesta con mas preguntas que los lleven a investigar y no se queden estancados con un copia y pega...

Comment: Gracias a todos por los criterios, desde que escribí la funcionalidad hasta hoy he aprendio un poquito más de eventos, y tengo más claro la manera en que se ´bindean´ las funciones, para que no se rompa el bind al recargar una región específica de la página. Ahnn, el crédito se lo llevan ustedes porque lo he aprendido leyendo en acá en la comunidad.

Comment: Marca como resuelto y escoje la respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Una de las formas correctas de hacerlo es

```
$('body').on('click', '#tablaRiesgos tbody tr a.lnkEliminarRiesgo', function(e) { ... }
```

De esta manera, mantienes el evento enlazado al elemento body (que en teoría, no variará en el DOM de tu aplicación) y realizas un filtrado sobre el selector `#tablaRiesgos tbody tr a.lnkEliminarRiesgo`, así no es necesario está enlazando continuamente un evento `click` con elementos de nueva creación.

Comment: es recomendable entonces enlazar todos los eventos al body ?.  Es que tengo un div central donde se cargan vía ajax las vistas y es apartir del id de ese div desde donde enlazo los enventos de las etiquetas <a>. Creo debo abrir otra pregunta porque es una duda un poco más específica.

Comment: Está un poco basado en la opinión y experiencia de cada uno, hay quien prefiere enlazarlo al elemento body, otros al document. La cuestión es que lo hagas sobre un elemento fijo del `DOM`. No obstante, usar `document` para ello tiene un coste de ejecución mayor, ya que document suele ser un elemento mayor que body.